# Error: ERR value is not an integer or out of range from redis.call('zcard','myzset') in LUA script

Tags: node.js, lua, redis

I have this code in a lua script which I run from node.js.

```
local stats = {};
stats['orders'] = redis.call('zcard','jobs');

return cjson.encode(stats)
```

This returns the error :

> Error: ERR value is not an integer or out of range

However when I run `zcard jobs` from the CLI an integer is returned.

Comment: sidenote that you don't need semi-colons in Lua

Comment: thanks for this, the problem was in how I was calling the lua script :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Lua script works fine. Throw away the semicolons tho, it's Lua ;) .

*Test:*

```
redis-cli -p 14130 eval "local stats = {} \
stats['orders'] = redis.call('zcard','azbp.d') \
return cjson.encode(stats)" 0
```

*Result:*

```
"{\"orders\":10424}"
```

My guess is, that your client side call is invalid. The first parameter so pass to `EVAL` or `EVALSHA` should be the number of parameters. You must pass 0 in this example. Just guessing ofcourse.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer, so it's won't show up in 'unanswered' lists that other ppl look at.

Comment: @user3244480, sorry if this sounds pedantic, but my guess is that you're new to SO. I also guess that you upvoted the answer, instead of accepting the answer as 'the' answer. I'm not fishing for points btw, you can just as well post an answer of your own, and accept that one as the answer. If I'm guessing this all wrong, ignore this comment.